# Extract data from specific cells from unworkable excel files (300+) to newly formatted excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net, cell

I have very little experience with C (working on psets from CS50x course) and I do some AutoLISP coding at work. I am currently working getting VB installed on my computer but I can install a different IDE/language if it works better. I am open to learning how to tackle this problem.

Basically, I am getting 300+ excel documents that are not formatted in a workable way (they look nice when they print but useless to try to examine the data across all sheets if I combined them all into one sheet like I saw with a tutorial).

Luckily, they are all formatted exactly the same. I am trying to figure out how to extract data from specific cells that are consistent in every file to a new excel file.

My pseudocode is looking something like this:

```
Locate the excel files

 Create new excel file

  Iterate through the excel file list

   Open nth Excel file

    Read first set of specific cells and add to array
    Write array to nth row in new excel file
    Read second set of specific cells and add to array
    Write array to nth row in new excel file

   Close nth Excel File

 Close new excel file
```

Any hints, tips and advice is greatly appreciated. This is my first time trying to do something like this.

Comment: Your question is too broad in scope for single question/topic->answer site like SO and will likely be closed.  Take each task in your pseudo-code and research it/attempt to code it.  Then ask a specific question on each the part that you can not make work.  Like most difficult tasks in life, the solution is to divide into conquerable parts and then assemble the whole solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll approach that way.

Comment: You don't need to install VB. Just use VBA. Your question as is can't be answered - you need to be more specific. You need to start by writing a very simple program in VBA that can copy/paste excel values. YOu start doing this by recording a macro, then examine the code in the macro, then do some googling

Answer (score 0):

It would help if I knew more about the data you are trying to extract. 
You can run this sub in a new excel file(tested in Excel 2010) using VBA(might be better than creating a new file through a vb.net application):

```
Private Sub ExtractData()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim strPath As String
Dim intLen As Integer
Dim strName As String
Dim strValue As String
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim wsFind As Worksheet

On Error GoTo errExtract

Set wsSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set sheet you want to extract the data to
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strPath = "C:\Users\pcool\Desktop\FolderName" 'Set path of folder with excel files
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath) 'Get the folder object associated with the directory
wsSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Title of Data"


For Each objFile In objFolder.Files 'Loop through the files in the folder
    Workbooks.Open (strPath & "\" & objFile.Name)

    Set wsFind = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name of sheet in excel file

    strValue = wsFind.Range("B8").Value 'Grab specific cell value "B8" from file
    wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = strValue 'Put value in first available cell in new file

    ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False 'Skip compatibility check

    intLen = Len(objFile.Name) - 5 'Remove .xlsx characters from name
    strName = Left(objFile.Name, intLen)

    Workbooks(strName).Close SaveChanges:=False 'Close excel file without saving

 Next

ExtractExit: 'Exit and set objects to nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Exit Sub

errExtract: 'Error handler
MsgBox (Err.Description)
Resume ExtractExit

End Sub
```